# Implementing a Visibility Toggle for Password Field in Flutter TextFormField

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-textformfield, custom-widgets

I'm working on a Flutter app where I need to implement a password field within a `TextFormField` that includes a visibility toggle (eye icon) to show/hide the password. Despite attempting to integrate this feature, I'm facing challenges with passing the visibility state to my custom `TextFormField` widget.

Here's what I currently have and what I aim to achieve (with images illustrating my design goal):

**Current Design:**

[image]

**Target Design with Visibility Toggle:**

[image]
[image]

**Relevant Code Snippets:**

*Profile.dart* snippet showcasing the password `TextFormField`:

profile.dart

```
class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
  Auth _auth = Auth.signUp;
  final _signUpFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _signInFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _nameController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _emailController.dispose();
    _passwordController.dispose();
    _nameController.dispose();
  }

  bool isHiddenPassword = true;

 ...child: Form(
                            key: _signUpFormKey,
 ...CustomTextField(
                                  controller: _passwordController,
                                  hintText: 'Password',
                                  style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                                    color: const Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    fontSize: 20.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
```

*custom_textfield.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class CustomTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final String hintText;
  final TextStyle style;
  const CustomTextField({
    Key? key,
    required this.controller,
    required this.hintText,
    required this.style,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomTextField> createState() => _CustomTextFieldState();
}

class _CustomTextFieldState extends State<CustomTextField> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          fontSize: 20.0,
            
          
        ),
        controller: widget.controller,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: widget.hintText,
          border: const OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Color(0xff3B3B3B),
          )),
          enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Color(0xff3B3B3B),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        validator: (val) {
          return null;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my toggle:

```
  bool isHiddenPassword = true;
TextField(
                            obscureText: isHiddenPassword,
                            cursorColor: const Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: '8+ Characters',
                              hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0, color: Color(0xffD7D7D7)),
                              suffixIcon: InkWell(
                                onTap: _togglePasswordView,
                                child: isHiddenPassword
                                    ? const Icon(
                                        Icons.visibility_off,
                                        color: Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                                      )
                                    : const Icon(
                                        Icons.visibility,
                                        color: Colors.grey,
                                      ),
                              ),
                              enabledBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide:
                                    BorderSide(color: Color(0xffD7D7D7)),
                              ),
                              focusedBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide:
                                    BorderSide(color: Color(0xffD7D7D7)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                              decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.dotted,
                              decorationColor: Color(0xffF6F6F6),
                              fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(59, 59, 59, 1),
                            ),
                          ),
                  
  void _togglePasswordView() {
    setState(() {
      isHiddenPassword = !isHiddenPassword;
    });
  }
```

**My Question:**

How can I ensure the visibility toggle (eye icon) properly toggles the visibility of the password in my custom `TextFormField` widget? I'm having difficulty passing the isHiddenPassword state and the `_togglePasswordView` function to control the visibility from my `Profile` widget to the custom `CustomTextField` widget.

Any guidance or examples on how to achieve this functionality would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `isHiddenPassword` is just needed and update on the `_CustomTextFieldState` you dont need to worry about parent widget. But if you like to use it for all textFiled, It would be better to add a widget params to check if it password type or not. I am setting default is false.

```dart
class CustomTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final String hintText;
  final TextStyle style;
  final bool isPasswordFiled;

  const CustomTextField({
    Key? key,
    required this.controller,
    required this.hintText,
    required this.style,
    this.isPasswordFiled = false,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomTextField> createState() => _CustomTextFieldState();
}

class _CustomTextFieldState extends State<CustomTextField> {
  bool isHiddenPassword = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        obscureText: widget.isPasswordFiled && isHiddenPassword,
        style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          fontSize: 20.0,
        ),
        controller: widget.controller,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          suffixIcon: widget.isPasswordFiled
              ? InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      isHiddenPassword = !isHiddenPassword;
                    });
                  },
                  child: isHiddenPassword
                      ? const Icon(
                          Icons.visibility_off,
                          color: Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                        )
                      : const Icon(
                          Icons.visibility,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                )
              : null,
          hintText: widget.hintText,
          border: const OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Color(0xff3B3B3B),
          )),
          enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Color(0xff3B3B3B),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        validator: (val) {
          return null;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I thought that I will have problems with `_emailController` and `_nameController`, but it works nicely!

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [widgets](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets)